# How to save image in opencv after thresholding using imwrite

Tags: python, opencv, threshold

I'm trying to save an image using cv2.imwrite after thresholding but it doesnt save the image. below is the code I'm using:

```
import necessary packages

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
    help = "Path to the image to be thresholded")

ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type = int, default = 128,
    help = "Threshold value")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

methods = [("THRESH_BINARY", cv2.THRESH_BINARY)]

for (threshName, threshMethod) in methods:

    (T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(gray, args["threshold"], 255, threshMethod)

    cv2.imshow(threshName, thresh)

    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite(gray, args["image"])
```

Comment: `cv2.imwrite(args["image"], gray)` -- file name goes first.

Comment: the code runs...but the image doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to save the thresh image. `cv2.imwrite(args["image"], thresh)` should be inside the for loop.